# Service application cannot be deleted

Tags: project-server, pwa

I am working on project server , I created PWA application service, and I can't delete it due to existing project sites. How do I delete the service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be aware of you can't delete `Project Server application service` if it's associated with PWA site collections. So you can’t delete it until delete all related project sites instances as the following:

- Open Central Administration > Below Application management > Mange Service application > Click on your Project server application service > and delete all instances.

[image]

- After you delete all instances ,  try to delete the PS application service , that should be deleted successfully .

You can also do this via PowerShell as mentioned at [Service application cannot be deleted due to existing project sites](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/22/service-application-cannot-be-deleted-due-to-existing-project-sites/)

Answer (score 2):

- Backup all your project sites.
- Delete all your project sites.
- In all your farm servers, open the Services.msc snap-in, and restart the
  following services:

  - SharePoint 2013 Administration
  - SharePoint 2013 Timer
  - SharePoint 2013 Tracing
  - SharePoint 2013 User Code Host
  - SharePoint 2013 VSS Writer
  - World Wide Web Publishing
  - Service SharePoint Server Search
- On the server that is running the SharePoint Central Administration
  website, at a command prompt, type iisreset.
- Then try to delete the Service Application again

Comment: you're welcome, good to know that you found a solution for your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly there will be orphan PWA instance which is causing this issue. You can run below PowerhSell Commands to find out orphan PWA Instance.

```
 $serviceapp = get-spserviceapplication | ? {$_.TypeName –like “*Project*”} 
 $pwainstances = $serviceapp.Sitecollection 
 $pwainstances
```

To delete the Orphan instance use below command without closing PowerShell Window.

```
$toberemoved = $pwainstances | ? {$_.Id –eq “<Id of the instance to delete>”} 
$toberemoved 
$toberemoved.Delete()
```